# Linear Algebra Spanning question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I have two $3\times1$ column vectors in a vector space $V$ that are linearly independent, how can I make a system of $3$ eqns whose solution will span $V$?

For example,

column vector $[1,3,0]$, column vector $[1,0,-1]$, so these vectors form $V$. What third vector can I make so that it will span $S$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: find a vector orthogonal to both (e.g. take vector product $[1,3,0]\times [1,0,-1]$...)

Comment: what?? im lost... could you just show me how to do it?

Comment: The vector product $[1,3,0]\times [1,0,-1]=[-3,1,-3]$ is orthogonal to both $[1,3,0]$ and $[1,0,-1]$. The triple $[1,3,0], [1,0,-1], [-3,1,-3]$ is a base for the whole space $\mathbb{R}^3$. For how to compute the cross product, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: But how does that satisfy the solution space if it's orthogonal...?

Comment: they span the whole space. what do you mean by "satisfy the solution space"? If you have nontrivial equations, then the solution space is less than the whole space...